# Kendo UI Grid inline edit not work when use ObservableArray as data for data source

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use a kendo.data.ObservableArray as data for data source of the grid. It shows ok. When edit inline, change a field, then cancel, the values are changed. When clicking edit, then click edit on another row, the last one remains in the edit mode. Sometimes cancel not work. On the array it works as expected.

I took the Kendo UI Demo, http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline, to reproduce the issue. Here is the issue: http://dojo.telerik.com/uLiCi/2

Does anyone have any idea why so strange behavior?

In my opinion, it should work with both, array and observable array.

Thanks in advance